# PHP mysql result json_encode return key and index number

Tags: php, json

Why does the JSON output show both the index number and the association colume name?

I only need just column name such as "UID"

**PHP CODE**

```
$res = $statement->fetchAll();
$records = array('Record'=>$posts);
echo json_encode($records);
```

**JSON OUTPUT**

```
{
  "Record":[
    {
      "UID":"1001",
      "0":"1001",
      "NAME":"Robot2",
      "1":"Robot2",
      "EMAIL":"robot2@test.com",
      "2":"robot2@test.com",
      "GENDER":"f",
      "3":"f"
    },
    {
      "UID":"1030",
      "0":"1030",
      "NAME":"Anna",
      "1":"Anna",
      "EMAIL":"Anna@msn.com",
      "2":"Anna@msn.com",
      "GENDER":"f",
      "3":"f"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for an explaination:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

In order to only get the associative items, you should pass `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to your fetchAll.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me and giving accurate answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

The default fetch style is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, you need to set it to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

```
$res = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or you could set the default **DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE** by:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then you could just do `$res = $statement->fetchAll();`

Comment: you guys are fast on the trigger... :-)